# What are the unused pins in an Arduino L293D motor shield?

Tags: motor, shields, pins

What are the unused pins in an Arduino L293D motor shield? I want to connect the shield using wires instead of directly mounting on top of the Arduino board.

[image: Arduino Motor Shield(L293D)]

Comment: Please edit your question to include [shield's maker and part number](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield) and  [tutorials](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AdafruitMotorShield), etc.   Add [a link to its schematic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Motor-Shield-for-Arduino/master/mshieldv12schem.png) if you have one.

Comment: It's similar to Adafruit's motor shield and works with Adafruit's motor library.

Comment: What if I don't use servo motor, Can I still use pin 9 and 10 as normal digital pins ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [Link](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AdafruitMotorShield). Here, you can find this explanation in Code. I hope it will helpful for you.

```
Pin usage with the Motorshield
---------------------------------------
Analog pins: not used at all...
A0 ... A5 are still available...
They all can also be used as digital pins.
Also, I2C (A4 = SDA and A5 = SCL) can be used.
These pins have a breadboard area on the shield.
Digital pins: used: 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
Pin 9 and 10 are only used for the servo motors.
Already in use: 0 (RX) and 1 (TX).
Unused: 2,13
Pin 2 has an soldering hole on the board, easy to connect a wire.
Pin 13 is also connected to the system led.
I2C is possible, but SPI is not possible since those pins are used.
```